# PHP openssl_seal always generate empty encrypted_keys

Tags: php, openssl

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy).

Every time I call openssl_seal(), it always generates empty encrypted_keys.

I have enabled OpenSSL in PHP:

```
❯ php -i | grep -i openssl
SSL Version => OpenSSL/3.0.2
libSSH Version => libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Has anyone experienced the same situation before, and how did you handle the problem?

Comment: It may be helpful if you add the version of Ubuntu to the question. Use edit and add it not in comments please.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is the problem with OpenSSL? Or with PHP's `openssl_seal()` function? The two are very different. If it's with the PHP function, there are a minimum of 4 variables that need to be provided in order for it to encrypt. The function itself does not create the encryption keys.

Comment: Hi @matigo, I have provided all the parameters with complete values.

Comment: I'm seeing an incomplete set of information. If this is "all the parameters", then it's pretty obvious why the PHP function doesn't do anything ... because it's not being provided any criteria/

Comment: What directory (full path) are you trying to write to, what are it's permissions (`ls -l`), and what UID and GID are you running as? Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I discovered that OpenSSL 3 had removed support for the insecure algorithm I am forced to still use. After adding the legacy provider to the openssl config file and restarting apache, it works for me now. Reference this from OpenSSL https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/migration_guide.html#Legacy-Algorithms and you can reference this article to add the legacy provider... https://www.practicalnetworking.net/practical-tls/openssl-3-and-legacy-providers/